# How to generate a CSV file from Mongoid data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have a Ruby on Rails application running with Mongodb. I have a model called `Label` and  I have added some data to it.

I am trying to generate a CSV file from the `index` method in the Labels controller.

I added the following code in the `index` method:

```
respond_to do |format|
format.html
format.csv { send_data @labels.to_csv, filename: "labels-#{Date.today}.csv" }
end
```

I added a method `to_csv` in the controller:

```
def self.to_csv(options={})
    attributes = %w{name manufacturing_date digital_signature1}

    @all_labels=Label.all
      csv << attributes
      @all_labels.each do |label|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| label.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
```

But when I actually generate a CSV file, it gives me a file where there is no data. I get six column names like:

```
#<Label:0x00007f637ac2e130>, #<Label:0x00007f637ac2e090>, #<Label:0x00007f637ac2dfc8>, #<Label:0x00007f637ac2db18>, #<Label:0x00007f637ac2d9d8>, #<Label:0x00007f637ac2d668>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are following https://www.codementor.io/@victor_hazbun/export-records-to-csv-files-ruby-on-rails-vda8323q0 the to_csv method should be added to the model, not to the controller.

Comment: I did move the to_csv method to the model, but the result is the same.